# How to fix scrolling issue with Telerik Rad buttons

Tags: telerik, telerik-radbutton

I'm trying to fix an issue with a telerik rad button that occurs when scrolling after documents have been selected for uploading. The Select Files button stays at the top when scrolling which is what I want but the second button (Upload) does not stay at the top and instead scrolls and covers up the files that have been added via the Select Files button.

Here is the part of the code along with an image of the actual upload screen.

```
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="padding: 10px 0">
            <div class="col-lg-1" >
                <telerik:RadAsyncUpload RenderMode="Lightweight" 
                                        ID="RadUpload1" 
                                        runat="server" 
                                        MultipleFileSelection="Automatic" 
                                        ManualUpload="False" 
                                        DropZones=".DropZone1" 
                                        OnClientValidationFailed ="OnClientValidationFailed"
                                        PostbackTriggers="btnUpload"
                                        HideFileInput="False"
                                        UploadedFilesRendering="BelowFileInput"
                                        OnClientFilesUploaded="onClientFilesUploaded"
                                        OnClientFileUploading="onClientFileUploading">
                    <Localization Select="Select files"></Localization>
                </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <telerik:RadButton RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" Text="Upload" ID="btnUpload" Enabled ="false"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="DropZone1">
            <p>Drop Files Here</p>
        </div>
```

[image: example snip]

Comment: Inspect with devtools and see which CSS properties are applied to the button - look for position: absolute or relative that can cause the scrolling issue.

Comment: Check out this forum for more information - https://www.telerik.com/forums/rad-button-controls-scroll-issue.